Loss function on intermediate layers of the networks
Typically in supervised learning, a neural networks' output is compared to the targets through a loss function, and the gradients are backpropagated. Is it a bad idea to also have a loss function on intermediate layers? I feel that restricts the networks ability to actually optimize the final, global loss function. What are the instances in which an additional loss on intermediate layers would work?
----EDIT----
Clarification of my thought process for supervising intermediate layers, via examples:

Merging contrastive loss to a Variational AutoEncoder (VAE) or a Classifier. I would have the original VAE loss function (or classifier's cross entropy loss), but additionally supervise the output of the encoder or some intermediate layer with a contrastive loss (for example the triplet loss, where the targets would be positive and negative samples from the batch)

A more classic example would be teacher-student distillation, supervising student's intermediate layers with the teacher's intermediate layers.

When intermediate layers provide a prediction itself. For instance, let's say we have an object detector where the Mth layer outputs segmentation masks, and the Nth layer (N>M) outputs the bounding boxes.


So the question is, when would these additional losses work, or will they confuse the network just more?

Can you explain how you would compute such a loss? What would be the targets, for example? Maybe your idea makes sense, but right now it's a bit unclear. So, backpropagation is a global update rule. Maybe you have some local update rule in mind?

@nbro yes thank you for the question. I edited my post with to exemplify my idea in mind. Let me know if I should elaborate more.
